# Initialize protocol in a class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, protocols, swift-protocols

```
protocol Engine {
       func setSpeed(speed: Double)
}
struct Car: Engine {
       let speed: Double

       func setSpeed(speed: Double) {

           self.speed = speed
       }
}
class RandomViewController: UIViewController {
      let engine: Engine
}
```

I saw a video of someone who demonstrated protocol oriented in Swift and I was taken with it. The person did something like this and seemed to get no errors.

I get the error Class 'RandomViewController' has no initializers. Where am I off? Could someone correct me and point me at the right direction?

EDIT: The video is https://youtu.be/-g53kYDIpP4?t=611 
EDIT2: Didn't listen through the video.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you declare constant which is not Optional and don't initialise it.

```
  let engine: Engine
```

You should declare it with var and make it optional or write initializer in you RandomViewController and init your constant there.

**UPDATE**

Example

```
protocol Engine {
    mutating func setSpeed(speed: Double)
}

struct Car: Engine {
    var speed: Double = 0

    mutating func setSpeed(speed: Double) {
        self.speed = speed
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let engine:Engine

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        engine = Car(speed: 5);
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        engine = Car(speed: 5);
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: init(engine: Engine) { self.engine = Engine } forces me to implement a init from the viewcontroller.

Comment: Anyway, doesn't seem to be a good solution. I might be wrong.

Comment: This is a strict type Swift, if you declare that it is not optional constant then you have to initialise it in init or right as where you declare it

Comment: Could you give an example

Comment: @bCM write `let engine: Engine!` and don't forget to assign value before use. Read documentation about initializers when you have time; inhered initializers provided implicitly, **but** only until you write at least one initializer explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, this working on this sample. But in my project the same thought process doesn't work.

Comment: @bCM if this solution solves your problems, could you mark it as correct answer?

Comment: According to the topic question and answer then ok. Otherwise it didn't really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Change it as following and initialize it before you use it:

```
var engine: Engine!
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I had variables inside my struct on a global scale which cause the problem. Whenever I tried to use the protocol as a type it complained about it need to be initialized.

I had to dissolve the protocol and struct and assemble it a different way that solved my issue.